# Accessing the PyQt4 interface from multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a very easy PyQt interface, tabs and buttons. I have added a text box to show the results of an execution, a popen, in the background, in another thread. In my production machine I only get a failure of segmentation, while in development machines (all virtual) works as expected.

All the machines, both virtual and physical, are an Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS of 32 bits. Python2.7, PyQt4, all installed from apt. (I have to use hardware that I only get it to work in 32 bits).

I have tried to execute the EXACT code in different machines, and in all of them it works more or less well, less in the production, it crash.

```py
import os, sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep
from nbstreamreader import NonBlockingStreamReader as NBSR
import threading
from time import sleep
class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    textbox=""
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setGeometry(0,0, 500,650)
        self.setWindowTitle("Xarxa Rescat")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.resize(500,650)
        self.setMinimumSize(500,650)
        self.center()
......
        self.textbox = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(20, 20)
        self.textbox.resize(280,300)
......
    def addText(self, text):
    self.textbox.appendPlainText(text)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
frame = MainWindow()
frame.show()

def outputs(nbsrObj,qtframe):
    while True:
        output = nbsr.readline(0.1)
        # 0.1 secs to let the shell output the result
        if output is not None:
            frame.addText(output)
    return

sleep(1)
p = Popen(['sudo', 'ls', '-lisah'],
       stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = False, bufsize = 1)

nbsr = NBSR(p.stdout)
t = threading.Thread(target=outputs, args=(nbsr,frame,))
t.start()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Expected: that an ls be executed, that my NBSR class get the stdout and call the addText function that will add the result of the ls to the text field.

Example running on the virtual machine:
[image: Working example]

In the image you can see, in the terminal, how a first execution triggers in a Segmentation Fault, which causes the program to terminate automatically. This is exactly what always happens to me in the physical machine.

Comment: Qt does not support access to GUI objects from multiple threads.   You’ll need to have your background thread send the data to the main/GUI thread (eg via QApplication’s postEvent() method, or a queued signal/slot connection), and then display the data from the main thread.

Comment: @jeremy-friesner I understand your reasoning, what I do not understand is then why in the virtual machine it works.

Comment: It’s the nature of race conditions that sometimes things seem to work and sometimes they do not.

Comment: @user1814720 What JeremyFriesner indicates is not optional, it is mandatory

Comment: Ok, well, thanks to all :) I'm going to Google this!